# Make bar go from right to left using google.visualization.DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

Is it possible to reverse the direction of a chart(bar) using google.visualization.DataTable?
As shown in the image below the bar is going from left to right, but I want it to go from right to left. This is what I have done so far when it comes to changing the appearance of the table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
      {
        dataTable.setProperties(i, 0, {style: 'text-align: center;'}); 
        dataTable.setProperties(i, 1, {style: 'text-align: center;'}); 
      } 

      var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
      table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
      var options = {'allowHtml' : true};
```

But I don't see any way to change the graph direction.

[image]

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this:

```
  var formatter = new google.visualization.TableBarFormat({base: 0, showValue: false, min: 0, max: max_graph, colorPositive: 'red'});
  formatter.format(dataTable, 5);
  formatter = new google.visualization.TableBarFormat({base: 0, showValue: false, min: -max_graph, max: 0, colorNegative: 'blue'});
  formatter.format(dataTable, 2);
```

Hence, I just alter the different columns I need and format the table for each column.